# Does anyone have experience using Backbone.js and Pylons/Pyramid ? any sample to look at?

Tags: javascript, python, backbone.js, pylons, pyramid

Does anyone have experience using Backbone.js and Pylons/Pyramid ? any sample to look at ?

Comment: I used backbone.js and webapp on gae with python, if this is any help.

Comment: https://github.com/ichbinadrian/maps

Answer (score 3):

[Pyramid Backbone Playground](https://github.com/jsaxon-cars/Pyramid-Backbone-Playground) is a fully-working example that you can checkout from github; he also references a [Backbone.js and Django blog post](http://joshbohde.com/blog/backbonejs-and-django) that you might also find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Cornice (http://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for creating your web services in Pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on your question a little bit? What are you looking to do?

I have worked with backbone and pylons/pyramid, but they interface with each other and are not integrated. Backbone talks to the API which was built using pyramid.